# CiviRule delay is not working

Tags: civirules

I've set up a new rule. When I'm testing it without a delay, it works as expected. But when I set a delay, it doesn't seem to be executed. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Dear Itamar

Could it probably be a mismatch of the server-time with the configured time(-zone) in your cms which is leading to this behaviour?

Comment: Are both scheduled jobs enabled - there's a separate one for delayed rules?